# Ho to copy text to clipboard and paste into MS Word table?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, clipboard, copy-paste

I need to copy some values from textBox1 and textBox2 to clipboard by clicking on button "Copy To Clipboard". After that I open Word document, place the cursor into the table and press "Ctrl+V".

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9udY2.jpg)

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
            Clipboard.SetText(TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text)
        Else
            Clipboard.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to paste the values into the table cells, but I can't do this, because it paste into one cell all the values.

Comment: you glued 2 strings together so thats what you got.  you might have to write some code (gasp!)  to put 2 word table cells with those strings in them for it to work

Comment: Sorry, I misundertood you question. I though that you were expecting the application to perform the pasting automatically. I chose the wrong reason when voting to put this post on hold: it is not because of being too broad (what would be in case of having to deal with all the MS Office automatisation), but because of belonging to other SE site: SuperUser. Knowing how to paste information in a Word table is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

If you separate the values with a tab, they will paste into separate cells in Word, but *only* if you select multiple cells before pasting.  If you have a single cell selected, it will paste the tab separated values into that single cell (Word 2010, others may be different).

```
Clipboard.SetText(TextBox1.Text & vbTab & TextBox2.Text)
```

Hopefully someone else knows a cleaner way.  For example, if you copy cells from Excel, there are additional paste options in Word (e.g. Overwrite Cells seems to be what you are looking for), and presumably these are triggered by Excel putting the data onto the clipboard in different formats.

Comment: This answer is not intending to fix a programming problem, but the OP is not asking a programming question anyway. There are many ways to do it "cleaner" by relying on programming (i.e., letting the application take care of all the actions automatically). On the other hand, from a user perspective, if the goal is allowing to paste various values to different cells of a MS Word table, your solution seems to be the only option (separating the values with tabs + selecting all the target cells in the table).

Comment: @varocarbas By "cleaner way", I was wondering if there is a clipboard data format that could be used that would work better for pasting into a Word table.  For example, if you copy cells from Excel, there are additional paste options in Word (e.g. Overwrite Cells seems to be what the OP is looking for), and presumably these are triggered by Excel putting the data onto the clipboard in different formats.  This seems like a programming problem to me - how can the original code be modified so that the data pastes correctly into a Word table?  Of course, the question is open to interpretation. :-)

Comment: The problem is that the OP is not facing the copying from MS Word (where such a behaviour might happen), but from plain text pasting (the same behaviour you get in Notepad). If the OP also wants to involve MS Word automatisation, there would be various options; although all this would be outside the scope of the question. For what the OP is asking, your answer is perfect (but both question and answer are not exactly on-topic here, at least in my opinion). PS: I wasn't planning to upvote you (with the accepted mark should be enough), but the OP might not even accept it so...

Comment: @Mark, thank you very mach! I tried to write a Tab, but not thought to select two cells. If there is no other solution, then it is also nice. And I do not understand why my question was called not related to programming?